is there any way to check with cumulative way to get month based on the amount fields
I have one table as below mysql
customer_id,invoice_id,invoice_month,payment_month,invoice_amount,payment_amt,balance_amt
1,1,"DEC 23","JAN 24",400.00,400.00,0.00
1,2,"DEC 23","JAN 24",600.00,600.00,0.00
1,3,"JAN 24","JAN 24",200.00,50.00,150.00
2,4,"SEP 23","MAY 24",800.00,800.00,0.00
2,5,"OCT 23","MAY 24",750.00,750.00,0.00
3,6,"FEB 24","MAY 24",925.00,525.00,400.00
4,7,"NOV 22","JUN 23",325.00,325.00,0.00
4,8,"DEC 22","JUN 23",425.00,425.00,0.00
5,9,"JUN 24",NULL,500.00,NULL,500.00

Payment table as
customer_id,payment_month,amount
1,JAN 24,500
1,FEB 24,550
2,MAR 24,450
2,APR 24,900
2,MAY 24,450
3,MAY 24,525
4,JUN 23,350
4,JUN 23,400

need to create a new columns payment_final_month based on "payment_month" from the payment table.
For the first record i have invoice amount has 400 which is less than the payment table amount first record then pick JAN 24
For the second record as i have 100 left from the first record then pick the same JAN 24
For 3rd record i should pick the FEB 24
Final output something as
customer_id invoice_id  invoice_month   payment_month   invoice_amount  payment_amt balance_amt payment_final_month
1   1   DEC 23  JAN 24  400.00  400.00  0.00    JAN 24
1   2   DEC 23  JAN 24  600.00  600.00  0.00    JAN 24
1   3   JAN 24  FEB 24  200.00  50.00   150.00  FEB 24
2   4   SEP 23  MAR 24  800.00  800.00  0.00    MAR 24
2   5   OCT 23  APR 24  750.00  750.00  0.00    APR 24
3   6   FEB 24  MAY 24  925.00  525.00  400.00  MAY 24
4   7   NOV 22  JUN 23  325.00  325.00  0.00    JUN 23
4   8   DEC 22  JUN 23  425.00  425.00  0.00    JUN 23
5   9   JUN 24  NULL    500.00  NULL    500.00  NULL

I tried below approach and didnt worked
i.invoice_amount - COALESCE(LAG(i.payment_amt, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY i.customer_id ORDER BY i.invoice_id), 0) AS remaining_amount


Can you redesign to include dates as date datatype and store actual dates?

@P.Salmon . Thanks a lot for the response. I may not be able to modifying with dates as I have the dates in the same format of MON YY. Is there any suggestion you may help me ..

@ysth. Thanks a lot for the comment. Is there any suggestion i can try pls

@ysth 100 should be considered for next record. As part of 1st recod out of 500 400 is less than 500 and 100 is remaining and that the reason for 2nd record as well it should pick the JAN 24. It should go in an ascending order and pick the next highest value based on difference of Invoice with payment

invoice_id 2 had 100 paid JAN 24 and the remaining 500 paid FEB 24, why is payment_final_month supposed to be JAN 24?

do you really not have a primary key for the payments table?

This is a bit messy cause there are some design issues regarding keys, relations and (especialy) dates.
You should convert your month strings into date datatypes to solve this. One way to do it is using cte for date datatype conversions and calculating running summs (cumulatives) for invoice and payment amounts.
So, with your sample data:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    invoices (customer_id, invoice_id, invoice_month, payment_month, 
              invoice_amount, payment_amt, balance_amt) AS
      ( Select 1, 1, 'DEC 23', 'JAN 24', 400.00, 400.00,   0.00 Union All 
        Select 1, 2, 'DEC 23', 'JAN 24', 600.00, 600.00,   0.00 Union All
        Select 1, 3, 'JAN 24', 'JAN 24', 200.00,  50.00, 150.00 Union All
        Select 2, 4, 'SEP 23', 'MAY 24', 800.00, 800.00,   0.00 Union All
        Select 2, 5, 'OCT 23', 'MAY 24', 750.00, 750.00,   0.00 Union All
        Select 3, 6, 'FEB 24', 'MAY 24', 925.00, 525.00, 400.00 Union All
        Select 4, 7, 'NOV 22', 'JUN 23', 325.00, 325.00,   0.00 Union All
        Select 4, 8, 'DEC 22', 'JUN 23', 425.00, 425.00,   0.00 Union All
        Select 5, 9, 'JUN 24', NULL,     500.00, NULL,   500.00
      ), 
    payments (customer_id, payment_month, amount) AS
      ( Select 1, 'JAN 24', 500 Union All
        Select 1, 'FEB 24', 550 Union All
        Select 2, 'MAR 24', 450 Union All
        Select 2, 'APR 24', 900 Union All
        Select 2, 'MAY 24', 450 Union All
        Select 3, 'MAY 24', 525 Union All
        Select 4, 'JUN 23', 350 Union All
        Select 4, 'JUN 23', 400
      ), 

... first create a cte that will be used for months to be converted into dates...
--  months conversion cte
    dates (mon, mm) AS
      ( Select  'JAN', '01' Union All
        Select  'FEB', '02' Union All
        Select  'MAR', '03' Union All
        Select  'APR', '04' Union All
        Select  'MAY', '05' Union All
        Select  'JUN', '06' Union All
        Select  'JUL', '07' Union All
        Select  'AUG', '08' Union All
        Select  'SEP', '09' Union All
        Select  'OCT', '10' Union All
        Select  'NOV', '11' Union All
        Select  'DEC', '12' 
      ), 

... next, create two more ctes for date conversion (using above cte) and for running summs of invoice and payment amounts ...
--  prepare payment data (cumulative sums and dates)
    payments_cumul AS
      ( Select p.customer_id, p.payment_month, p.amount, 
               STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01', d.mm, SubStr(p.payment_month, 5, 2)), '%d%m%y' ) as pay_date, 
               Sum(p.amount) Over(Partition By p.customer_id 
                                 Order By STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01', d.mm, SubStr(p.payment_month, 5, 2)), '%d%m%y' )
                                Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as pay_amt_cumul
        From   payments p
        Inner Join dates d ON( d.mon = SubStr(p.payment_month, 1, 3))
      ),

--  prepare invoice data (cumulative sums and dates)
    grid as
      ( Select    i.customer_id, i.invoice_id, 
                  i.invoice_month, i.payment_month as inv_payment_month, 
                  i.invoice_amount, 
                  Sum(i.invoice_amount) Over( Partition By i.customer_id, i.payment_month
                                              Order By STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01', d.mm, SubStr(i.payment_month, 5, 2)), '%d%m%y' )
                                              Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row
                                            ) as inv_amt_cumul,
                  i.payment_amt, i.balance_amt,
                  STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01', d.mm, SubStr(i.payment_month, 5, 2)), '%d%m%y' ) as inv_pay_date
        From      invoices i
        Left Join dates d ON( d.mon = SubStr(i.payment_month, 1, 3) )
      ) 

... finaly join it all together, aggregate and group by...
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select    g.customer_id, g.invoice_id,  
          Max(g.invoice_month) as invoice_month, 
          g.inv_payment_month,
          g.invoice_amount, g.payment_amt, g.balance_amt, 
          DATE_FORMAT(Case When g.inv_amt_cumul - Max(Coalesce(p.pay_amt_cumul, 0)) > 0
               Then Coalesce(Max(p.pay_date), g.inv_pay_date)  
          Else g.inv_pay_date
          End, '%M %y')  as payment_final_month
From      grid g
Left Join payments_cumul p ON( p.customer_id = g.customer_id And 
                               g.inv_amt_cumul >= p.pay_amt_cumul  
                             )
Group By g.customer_id, g.invoice_id, g.inv_payment_month, g.inv_pay_date, 
         g.invoice_amount, g.payment_amt, g.balance_amt
Order By g.customer_id, g.invoice_id

/*    R e s u l t :
customer_id invoice_id  invoice_month   inv_payment_month   invoice_amount  payment_amt balance_amt payment_final_month
----------- ----------  --------------  ------------------  --------------  ----------- ----------- -------------------
1                    1  DEC 23          JAN 24                      400.00       400.00        0.00 January 24
1                    2  DEC 23          JAN 24                      600.00       600.00        0.00 January 24
1                    3  JAN 24          JAN 24                      200.00        50.00      150.00 February 24
2                    4  SEP 23          MAY 24                      800.00       800.00        0.00 March 24
2                    5  OCT 23          MAY 24                      750.00       750.00        0.00 April 24
3                    6  FEB 24          MAY 24                      925.00       525.00      400.00 May 24
4                    7  NOV 22          JUN 23                      325.00       325.00        0.00 June 23
4                    8  DEC 22          JUN 23                      425.00       425.00        0.00 June 23
5                    9  JUN 24          null                        500.00         null      500.00 null        */

See the fiddle here.
UPDATE:  (  Error Code: 1270. Illegal mix of collations )
mixed collation within Concat() function causes the error. First two strings in concat are utf8 and the third one is latin1. Use explicite collation either on first two or on the third and make them all the same (all 4 Concatinations in code):
STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01',   -- utf8
                    d.mm,   -- utf8
                    SubStr(p.payment_month COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 5, 2)), 
           '%d%m%y' )

OR
STR_TO_DATE( Concat('01'  COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci, 
                    d.mm  COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci, 
                    SubStr(p.payment_month, 5, 2)),   -- latin1
            '%d%m%y' )


@d r , Thanks a  lot. I tried and getting error as
Error Code: 1270. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE), (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'concat'

@Arya Just posted an update regarding this error.
